# how to choose value in 1 column that must have 2 values in another - sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

table:

```
id   lesson
11  11 A
8   11 B
4   11 A
4   11 A
2   11 A
6   11 A
5   11 A
13  11 A
11  11 B
```

the id 11 has both taught in classroom 11A, 11B. How to select the ids that have both values 11a,11b?

I tried this with no luck:

```
select id from table where lesson in '11A' and lesson in '11B'
```

because it gives empty table, because it can't be both 11a and b at the same time.

Comment: THen try an OR and that syntax for `IN()` is wrong try a simple `=`

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's exectly two values you can make an inner join

```
select a.id 
from myTable a
inner join myTable b
on a.id = b.id 
and a.lesson = '11 A' and b.lesson = '11 B'
```

Answer (score 1):

for obtain  the id with both  the lesson

if could try using a subquery for the involved  id and the count if the id have more then a result

```
select id 
FROM (
    select id 
    from my_table 
    where lesson in ('11A', '11b')
) t 
group by id 
having count(*) = 2
```